# Question about Integrating in Polar Coordinates

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

If you have
$$
\int_0^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4 - x^2}} e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} dy \, dx
$$
and you convert to polar coordinates, you integrate from $0$ to $\pi/2$) with respect to theta.

But, if you have
$$
\int_{-6}^6 \int_0^{\sqrt{36-x^2}} \sin(x^2+y^2) \, dy \, dx
$$
and you convert to polar coordinates, you integrate from $0$ to $\pi$ with respect to theta. Can someone explain to me why the bounds of integration with respect to theta are different in these two problems? I'm having a hard time figuring it out. It would be a lot of help. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited your question with LaTeX/Mathjax; see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site/33183#33183) for more details on formatting math on this site. As a note, the lower limit of integration is always read first, so it's the integral from $0$ to $2$, not from $2$ to $0$. Regarding your question: have you drawn the regions of integration? The first is a quarter circle and the second is a semicircle, which explains the angles.

Comment: For whatever reason, I didn't understand the simple concept of the regions of integration. I understand now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's construct formal proof. In first case we have set
$$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{l}0 \leqslant x \leqslant 2 \\
0 \leqslant y \leqslant \sqrt{4-x^2}
\end{array}\right\rbrace$$
considering polar coordinates $x=r\cos \theta, y=r\sin \theta$ we will have from first inequalities $0 \leqslant r\cos \theta \leqslant 2 $ and $0 \leqslant r\sin \theta \leqslant \sqrt{4-(r\cos \theta)^2}$. From here we have for $\theta $ inequalities $0 \leqslant \sin \theta$ and $0 \leqslant \cos \theta$ which gives $\theta \in \left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. After analysis inequalities  $r \leqslant \frac{2}{\cos \theta}$ and $r \leqslant 2$ we have set

$$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{l}0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant \frac{\pi}{2} \\
0 \leqslant r \leqslant 2
\end{array}\right\rbrace$$
For second case analogical analysis gives

$$\left\lbrace \begin{array}{l}-6 \leqslant x \leqslant 6 \\
0 \leqslant y \leqslant \sqrt{36-x^2}
\end{array}\right\rbrace \to  \left\lbrace \begin{array}{l}0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant \pi \\
0 \leqslant r \leqslant 6
\end{array}\right\rbrace$$
As clevely is written  in adjacent answer from David G. Stork "Sometimes a picture is worth 1000 words". **But** the most best picture is not mathematical proof - good picture helps us to construct correct mathematical proof.

Comment: The OP asked "Can someone explain to me why the bounds of integration with respect to theta are different in these two problems?"... not a proof.  I'm pretty sure the OP will understand and remember my solution for a long time.

Comment: @David G. Stork. Word "explanation" can mean proof also, while proof, of course, is kind of explanation.

Comment: "Proof" is a *subset* of explanation, of course.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. This helped me to understand, and I understand now!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a picture is worth 1000 words:

[image]

---

```
Graphics[
 {Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 2, {0, \[Pi]/2}],
  Opacity[0.1], Green, Disk[{0, 0}, 6, {0, \[Pi]}]},
 Axes -> Automatic]
```

Comment: dear sir, I humbly ask, how do you draw such marvelous pictures???

Comment: 30 seconds in *Mathematica*.

Comment: you've sold me on Mathematica, thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for the solution! I understand now.